# Aggregation query to return most recent messages to and from User A not working properly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `MostRecentMessage` model, defined as,

```
const MostRecentMessage = new Schema({
  to: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user"
  },
  from: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user"
  },
  conversation: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "conversation"
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

Whenever User A sends a message to User B, a document is created if it doesn't exist. Every time User A sends User B a message, this document is updated with the new `conversation` and `date`. An example of a documents is,

```
_id: ObjectId(5dc46521cf670a0017d2434d)
to: ObjectId(5dc464ce2fd75700178c1ad4) // User B
from: ObjectId(5dc464fc2fd75700178c1ad5) // User A
conversation: ObjectId(5dc465c6cf670a0017d24363)
date: 2019-11-07T18:40:33.242+00:00
__v: 0
```

The idea is that this would help track all recent messages to specific users.

Likewise, User B could send User A a message. A new document would be created, similar to the above,

```
_id: ObjectId(5dc46521cf670a0017d2434d)
to: ObjectId(5dc464fc2fd75700178c1ad5) // User A
from: ObjectId(5dc464ce2fd75700178c1ad4) // User B
conversation: ObjectId(5dc465c6cf670a0017d24363)
date: 2019-11-07T18:40:33.242+00:00
__v: 0
```

And this document would be updated with every new message that User B sends to User A.

Now, below is my aggregation query.. but the problem is that it only returns one conversation. There could be 10 Users talking to User A, but it would still return only one document.

```
  const { id } = req.user;

  try {
    await MostRecentMessages.aggregate(
      [
        {
          $match: {
            $or: [
              { from: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) },
              { to: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) }
            ]
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 1, from: 1, to: 1, conversation: 1, date: 1 } },
        { $sort: { date: -1 } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            from: { $first: "$from" },
            to: { $first: "$to" },
            date: { $first: "$date" },
            conversation: { $first: "$conversation" }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "conversations",
            localField: "conversation",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "conversation"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: { path: "$conversation" } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "to",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "to"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: { path: "$to" } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "from",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "from"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: { path: "$from" } }
      ],
      function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          return res.json(docs);
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    return res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Edit: what I have now:

With this code, if

```
User A messages User B, 'Test1'
User B messages User A, 'Test2'
User A messages User B, 'Test3'
```

then only `Test2` message will display for both Users. How can I get 'Test3' to display for both users?

```
    await MostRecentMessages.aggregate(
      [
        {
          $match: {
            $or: [
              { from: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) },
              { to: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) }
            ]
            // deletedBy: { $ne: id }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 1, from: 1, to: 1, conversation: 1, date: 1 } },
        { $sort: { date: -1 } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              userConcerned: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $eq: ["$to", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)]
                  },
                  then: "$to",
                  else: "$from"
                }
              },
              interlocutor: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $eq: ["$to", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)]
                  },
                  then: "$from",
                  else: "$to"
                }
              }
            },
            from: { $first: "$from" },
            to: { $first: "$to" },
            date: { $first: "$date" },
            conversation: { $first: "$conversation" }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "conversations",
            localField: "conversation",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "conversation"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: { path: "$conversation" } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "to",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "to"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: { path: "$to" } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "from",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "from"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: { path: "$from" } }
      ],
      function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          return res.json(docs);
        }
      }
```

Comment: I suspect the group stage of the pipeline. I'm not sure why you added it though, but try removing it and see if the aggregation works as you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. The reason I added it is because if User A sends a message to User B, and if user B sends a message to User A, two `MostRecentMessages` documents are created. Getting rid of `$group` would return both documents. I only want one returned per conversation. So that way, one item shows for the whole conversation, in which only either User A or User B is returned, as the last person who messaged. So if User A talks to User B and User C, getting rid of `$group` would return [6 documents](https://i.imgur.com/jRDIRAx.png).. but I only need 3 (latest messages)

Comment: @OTZ is right when suspecting the group stage. In this stage, what you do is group all results of previous stage (_id:null) and take only the first element element of each field. So after that, hou have only one document...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my comment, the group stage is responsible of the unique result you get. The trick is to create 2 fields, from 'from' or 'to' field (depending of the objectId you provide in param), representing the user you provide, and his interlocutor. (no matter of 'from' an 'to')
Here's the idea, but i cannot currently test the solution.

```
...

  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
      userConcerned: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$to",
              mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
            ]
          },
          then: "$to",
          else: "$from"
        }
      },
      interlocutor: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$to",
              mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
            ]
          },
          then: "$from",
          else: "$to"
        }
      }
    },
        from: { $first: "$from" },
        to: { $first: "$to" },
        date: { $first: "$date" },
        conversation: { $first: "$conversation" }
    }
  }
  ...
```

[Here's the POC](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eEKCBzjA1CB)

(If you don't really matter of 'from' and 'to', you can use the two new created fields for your lookup, and remove from and to of the group stage.

Hope it helps

---EDIT---
To complete and explain my answer : 
Grouping with this computed _id instead of null, will group any conversation between A and B (A->B or B->A), A and C, A and D,... A will allways be in 'userConcerned', the other the interlocutor. 
By this way, you will get a document for each conversation of A, with the latest message (thanks to previous $sort stage and $first accumulator) between A and his interlocutor, without taking care if A is sender or receiver (from or to) of the message.

Comment: Hello! It's almost what I need, however it always returns one of the users' latest message. If User A is chatting with User B, it will only User B's latest message. If User A replies, it will still return only User B's latest message.

Comment: it will return the latest message between A and any other user (latest for each 'interlocutor'), no matter if A is reveiving or sending the message.

Comment: Right, but it doesn't do that. If User A messages 'Test1' to User B, User B replies with 'Test2', and then User A replies with 'Test3', then only the Test2 message will show up. The 'Test1' message will show up first, as it's the first message in the conversation, but from there on, it will only show User B's messages.

Comment: I've updated the POC link in my answer : you'll see you're wrong. It returns the last message between A and any other interlocutor.
Just to be sure : you do not copy my answer without adapting it to your needs ($eq:["$to", objectId("...")] must come from your params...)

Comment: Add `{ from: "A", to: "C", number: 3, message: "A-C Test 4" },` as the last element. Your query should return it, but instead it returns `{ "_id": { "interlocutor": "B", "userConcerned": "A" }, "from": "A", "lastMessage": "A-B Test 3", "num": 3, "to": "B" }`

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear in the question. I want the last messages displayed between two users, regardless of who sent it, User A or User B. In the solution that you provided, it does not do that (see the comment right before this one, above)

Comment: I accidentally edited your question instead of mine. Please look at what I have now. This code does not return the latest message

Comment: "Add { from: "A", to: "C", number: 3, message: "A-C Test 4" }"...
Dude, as i previously sort by number (you will do it with date), add the right number if you want that working! 
try with { from: "A", to: "C", number: 4, message: "A-C Test 4" }

See the edited link.

Comment: It's not working for me, but working for you in your POC. I'll try to make it work for me, thank for your help